# Overlayscrollbar/react v2 not scrolling onkeydown

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tiptap

How to convert this into `overlayscrollbars-react` v2? seems like `scroll function` is not working in latest version.

```
 React.useEffect(
        function scrollSelectedItemIntoView() {
            overlayScrollbarsRef.current?.osInstance().scroll({
                el: selectedItemRef.current,
                scroll: {
                    y: 'ifneeded',
                    x: 'never',
                },
            })
        },
        [selectedIndex],
    )
```

I am expecting similar behavior in this codesandbox link. Click on **`Suggestions`** tab and type `@` when you press up & down keys the scrollbar will also scroll based on the selectedIndex of user.
[https://codesandbox.io/s/tiptap-0sqm3i?file=/src/extensions/suggestions/SuggestionDropdown.tsx:1061-1405](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-gauss-tvdbff?file=/src/data/mentions.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reached out to the dev of the package itself and he response with an updated solution.

**Updated Solution**:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-lucy-7igb9n?file=/src/extensions/suggestions/SuggestionDropdown.tsx

**Github Closed Issue:** https://github.com/KingSora/OverlayScrollbars/issues/513